# enums alternatives

Tags: c++, qt4, sqlite

i want to store the colors of a team but unfortunately i am using sqlite which do not support enums.I want to store the team colors like this:

```
id   |   team name   |  team colors

1      vikings           red,orange,white

2      angles            gold,black
```

What's the way to go?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way (not necessarily the best under all conditions) is to create a table named `colors` (for example):

```
table color
id | color
1    green
2    red
3    blue
....
```

That's your enum table. Your c++ enums can be casted into ints which can then be used as primary key values. But if you are storing this data in a relational store, I don't think you want to tie these to a code-level artifact like an enum. A change in the contents of the table must force a change in the code.

Then, in typical normalized fashion, you create a `relational attribute` table, to represent the many-to-many relationship between your teams and the color enums. The color_id field maps to the color's table primary key, and the team_id maps to the teams table primary key.

```
table team-colors (color_id + team_id == primary key)
color_id | team_id
1          1
2          1
2          2
3          2
....
```

And then you have your team's table

```
table teams
id    | name 
1       vikings
2       angles
....
```

to know the colors per team, have a view (or run a SQL) with the following SQL pseudocode

```
SELECT a.id as team_id, a.name, b.color, b.id as color_id
FROM teams a, colors b, team_colors c
WHERE a.id = c.team_id and b.id = team_colors.color_id
```

There are a lot of syntactic details that need to be worked on with this (and there are conditions where this might not be desirable, too many to discuss in one single post). However, this is the general idea, more or less.

Comment: I am thinking of a Comma Delimited List and JSON but the CDL way seems easier.

Comment: A better way of handling the colors would be to just encode the rgb values in the table, and use those when you need to draw (assuming you need to draw the colors).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a bit of overkill but how about a structure like this?

```
COLORS
id  color
1   red
2   orange
3   white
4   gold
5   black

TEAMS
id | team name | team colors
1    vikings     1
2    angles      2

TEAM COLORS
teamid | colorid
1        1
1        2
1        3
2        4
2        5
```

Some simple sql will then produce the list of colors you need.

On the other hand, you can just store the color names as you have.  You'll have to parse them in your application.

Comment: Pretty much what I suggested, too (+1). I prefer this over trying to use c++ native artifacts. Code for code and rdbms for data. Anything else is hard-coding data into the code IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Enums can be casted to integers. Say you have

```
enum Color { red = 1, orange = 2, white = 4, gold = 8, black = 0x10 };
Color teamColor = red | orange | white;
```

Then you can store the teamColor as integer `(int)teamColor`.

Comment: This still doesn't answer under what type of SQL structure this information is to be stored and retrieved. Since this seems to be relational data, I'd argue that this information should not be represented as enums - since a change in the data store involves changes in the code and viceversa. Data and its definition resides in one place only, in the db or in code. Not on both.

Answer (score 0):

An enum is essentially an int, why not store int-values then?

Comment: I do not want to store that way.

Comment: Buurman, there is still the question of how to structure the database tables in sqllite. So it is more complex than just casting values away from one form to another.